# Document.SendStringToExecuteメソッドを使用したとき、コマンドラインに表示されるメッセージを非表示にする方法を知りたい

Tags: ijcad

現在、IJCAD 2022で.NET API(C#)を使用して開発を行っています。

コマンドメソッド属性が"CommandFlags.Session"のコマンドでは、Editorクラスを使用せず
doc.SendStringToExecute("*.UNDO C N ", true, false, false);

doc.SendStringToExecute("*.UNDO A ", true, false, false);
　のようにする必要があると認識しています。
　doc.SendStringToExecute()を使用すると、Application.SetSystemVariable("CMDECHO", 0); を行っても、コマンドラインにメッセージが表示されてしまいます。メッセージを非表示にする方法を教えていただけませんか？
　※Editor.Commandメソッドの場合は、CMDECHO=0とすることで、コマンドラインに表示されるメッセージを非表示にできました。

```
/// <summary>
    /// 元に戻すを不可にする
    /// </summary>
    public static void DisableUndo() {
        var doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        var db = doc.Database;
        var ed = doc.Editor;

        var oldVar = Application.GetSystemVariable("CMDECHO");
        Application.SetSystemVariable("CMDECHO", 0);

        // UNDO[元に戻す]コマンド→[コントロール(C)]→[なし(N)]
        doc.SendStringToExecute("_.UNDO C N ", true, false, false);
        // UNDO[元に戻す]コマンド→[すべて(A)]
        doc.SendStringToExecute("_.UNDO A ", true, false, false);

        Application.SetSystemVariable("CMDECHO", oldVar);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> メッセージを非表示にする方法を教えていただけませんか？

CMDECHO システム変数は、AutoLISP command 関数を実行中に、プロンプトと入力内容をエコー表示するかどうかを指定します。
Document.SendStringToExecute()メソッドで送るコマンド文字列をLISP式にすると、CMDECHO=0のときにプロンプトとユーザ入力を非表示にすることができます。

参考：
https://support.ijcad.jp/hc/ja/articles/900006376903-CMDECHO-